# Using setValues() with arrays of different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a two-dimensional array in Google apps script that contains arrays of different lengths. I would like to set the values of the array in a spreadsheet. However, because the arrays inside it are different lengths, I receive an error that essentially says the range and the array height don't line up. I've listed an example of the structure of the array below.

I can make it work if I add empty values to each individual array so that they all match the length of the longest array. This seems like a workaround though. Is there another way that I can set the values of the two-dimensional array?

```js
var array = [
  [a],
  [b,c],
  [d,e],
  [],
  [f,g,h,i],
  [],
  [j,k],
  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. The dimensions must match.

What you can do if you have few "rows" with great length difference, is to set each row on it's own.

```
for( var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i )
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, array[i].length).setValues([array[i]]);
```

But that's just another workaround. But working on your array to make all lengths match and do a single `setValues` will probably perform better.

Comment: Thanks, Henrique. I appreciate the answer.

Comment: henrique's answer is correct. I have added a simple workaround to redimension each row array as Henrique's answer suggested. Beware ive typed all this on my phone and not run it. Looks right though.

Answer (score 2):

In case your real array has many rows, individual writes will be expensive. Redimensioning each row array is fairly straightforward due to the way js handles arrays. A pattern similar to one i use is:

```
function myFunction() {
 var array = [
  [1],
  [2,2],
  [3,5],
  [],
  [0,0,0,0],
  [],
  [0,0],
 ];

 // get length of the longest row
 var max = array
  .slice(0)
  .sort(function (a,b) {
    return ( (a.length !== b.length) ? 1 : 0 );
  })[0].length;

 // arrays are zero indexed
 var maxi = max-1;

 // insert a pointer at max index if none exists
 array = array
  .map(function (a){ 
    a[maxi] = a[maxi] || ""; 
    return a; 
  });

 Logger.log(array);
}
```

Comment: Watch out! The short-circuit logic in `a[maxi] = a[maxi] || ""` will replace falsy values like `0` with empty string, which probably isn't what you want. Use strict equality instead: `if (a[maxi] === undefined) {a[maxi] = "";}`. (Also, you can replace `return a.length < b.length ? 1 : a.length > b.length ? -1 : 0;` with `return b.length - a.length`, since you need a positive number if `b` is bigger, a negative number if `a` is bigger, and `0` if they are the same).

Comment: @browly - the dangers of SO answering on a phone.

Comment: @Manohar see my previous comment. The critical issue is that `a[maxi] = a[maxi] || "";` will not pad the array correctly. It changes `[0,0,0,0]` to `[0,0,0,""]`. Also, your sort function won't work. It needs to return a negative value when `a` is longer than `b`. The most succinct way to do this is `b.length - a.length`. The desired output is `[[1, null, null, ""], [2, 2, null,""], [3, 5, null,""], [null, null, null,""], [0, 0, 0,0], [null, null, null,""], [0, 0, null,""]]`. Your script outputs `[[1], [2, 2], [3, 5], [], ["", 0, 0, 0], [], ["",0]]`

Comment: @browly Hmm, I think, I just edited/ translated what the author wrote. Didn't want to change the meaning of the author's thought, without he knowing it. My general view on answer is "I don't like the answer at all" :-), I won't write code that look like this, but who knows what author deep thoughts are. The best person now for you to talk is the author himself.

Comment: @Manohar No, the author wrote `a.length < b.length ? 1 : a.length > b.length ? -1 : 0;`, which returns `-1` when `a` is longer than `b`. What you wrote will only return `1` or `0`, never `-1`. Not the same.

Comment: @browly , oh, I would like to see a log what he wrote, please, so I can correct myself.