# google sheets query not able to transpose

Tags: google-sheets

can anyone tell why is this formula not working

```
=ARRAYFORMULA
(
   IF(isblank(H:H),"",IF(ROW(H:H)=5,"Previous meets",QUERY(mainDB2021!A:P,"select H WHERE D="&H6:H10000&"",0)))
```

)

[sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T2MUMw6bg9K55-wHDM8AYIFgdyD7Da5wS0vpIp_CiOU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transpose not working inside arrayformula in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814754/transpose-not-working-inside-arrayformula-in-google-sheets)

Comment: It is somewhere close but not exactly what I am looking for. I need to get the previous visit comments against the current date . The link you shared lists out all the contact numbers and all the comments. This is good for indexing but it will not solve my problem.

Comment: If do not accept more than 3 sections, here you have more `IF(isblank(H:H),"",IF(ROW(H:H)=5,"Previous meets",` . Where is located your formula ? In any case, pls give us a minimum reproducible spreadsheet.

Comment: I have used a nested if . The link to sheet is given , the name of subsheet is daily_log

Answer (score 1):

I created a new sheet ("daily_log_Erik"). There, I deleted all of your formulas from Column I and replaced them with one array formula in I5:

`=ArrayFormula({"Previous Meets"; IF(A6:A="",, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F6:F,FILTER(mainDB2021!D:H,INT(mainDB2021!A:A)<>A1),5,FALSE),"--"))})`

I believe this is what you are trying to do.

Since your `mainDB2021` sheet does not currently contain any data for dates past August 11, you can test my formula by simply modifying the A1 formula there from `=TODAY()` to `=TODAY()-7` (or minus some other number that will result in a date for which you do have data).

Essentially, the formula simply looks up the phone number from the current sheet within a version of the `mainDB2021` sheet data that is `FILTER`ed to remove the target date in the `daily_log` sheet. This way, `VLOOKUP` will always find that entry from the next-most-recent date. If none is found, `IFERROR` will return two dashes to signify that there was no previous date found.

Your sheet is currently processing very slowly. This is because you have over 50k rows in both your original `daily_log` sheet and in the sheet named `Copy_of_daily_log`. (This excess of rows usually means that there were failed attempts to create array formulas in those sheets.) Still, formulas are trying to process all of those blank rows, so they are slowing things down considerably. You will notice that my own new sheet only has 100 rows. If my solution works as you expect, you can simply delete your original `daily_log` sheet and the `Copy_of_daily_log` sheet, and then rename `daily_log_Erik` to `daily_log`.

Comment: hey erik , your formula formula works, but there is a small catch. I need to get the data of all the previous visits. In your solution it is displaying only single entry of previous visit. I have checked it from my end.
if we take entry from 17 aug, there is a visit from Akshat Mishra which is his third visit, but in your sheet it is displaying only 1 previous visit

Comment: Your post had very limited information provided. I wrote a formula based on that limited information. While what you are trying to do is possible, it goes beyond the scope of what a free forum run on the donated time of volunteers can provide. That is, writing the kind of formula you want would require an expert (which I am) and a time investment that would constitute what I'll call "real work" (which I cannot provide here). No forum is designed to provide custom, expert-level work at no cost. You are welcome to post again and try. But you may need to hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

After some grueling time trying to formulate, I wasn't able to solve it via sheets formula.

Seeing that you have a script on it, I tried creating a script instead. I was able to output the expected result into the specific cells, kindly check.

#### Code:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainDBsheet = ss.getSheetByName("mainDB2021");
  var numberRange = mainDBsheet.getRange("D2:D");
  var numberValues = numberRange.getDisplayValues().filter(String).flat();
  var meetRange = mainDBsheet.getRange("H2:H");
  var meetValues = meetRange.getDisplayValues().filter(String).flat();

  var dailySheet = ss.getSheetByName("daily_log");
  var dailyRange = dailySheet.getRange("F6:F");
  var dailyValues = dailyRange.getDisplayValues().filter(String).flat();

  // iterate daily_log!F6:F
  dailyValues.forEach(function (dailyNumber, index1){
    var matches = [];
    // iterate mainDB2021!D2:D
    numberValues.forEach(function (number, index2){
      // if mainDB2021!D2:D == the current daily_log!F6:F
      // save its mainDB2021!H2:H for later
      if(dailyNumber == number) 
        matches.push(meetValues[index2])
    });
    // all saved mainDB2021!H2:H are to be written per row as bulk
    dailySheet.getRange(index1 + 6, 9, 1, matches.length).setValues([matches]);
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Since the row length differs per row, it is impossible to output them by a single `setValues`. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864816/14606045)
- Tried having it as custom formula, and it seems it is very slow to return the multidimensional array. I used this approach instead as it is much faster.
- Tick `Enable Chrome V8 runtime` under Project Settings of the apps script.

[image: runtime]

Comment: hi nazia your code is showing error on line 5 for flat()

Comment: Hi @tinkershukla, you need to tick "Enable Chrome V8 runtime" in the project settings of the apps script. I edited the answer above to show how it looks like.

Comment: hi @tinkershukla, if this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)